# Getkey in matlab to record key presses

Tags: matlab

I want to be able to assign a key that when pressed will stop my script. I tried using getkey but I wasn't able to work it out

Answer (score 0):

It is more confort to use mouse position as a way to control the runtime.

For example, this will pause the script when you move the mouse to the left edge of the screen.

```
mymouse=get(0,'PointerLocation');
if mymouse(1)<4, keyboard;end
```

You can use multiple edge location for different actions.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is to create a figure, and then create a callback function for that figure that stops your script when you press a key.

For example:

```
function stoptest

%% Setup program
% create a figure for the application
myfig=figure;
% specify a callback function for the figure which will
%  listen for key presses
set(myfig,'KeyPressFcn', @stopkey);

data = []; k = 0;

%% Main Program Loop
% Use a global variable to control the loop
global RUNTEST;
RUNTEST=1;
fprintf(1,'Start MyFunction. Press alt-s to stop.\n');
while RUNTEST == 1
    % do whatever the loop does
    % maybe plot some data in the window
    % if the operator presses a key, it calls the figure callback function
    data = [data; k rand(1)];
    plot(data)

    drawnow;

end


function [] = stopkey(src,evnt)
% STOPKEY is a callback function that acts as the stop condition to cleanly
%  exit the test. It sets the value of RUNTEST to 0 when the user presses
%  <alt-s> in the progress figure (or <option-s> on a Mac).
global RUNTEST;
if length(evnt.Modifier) == 1 && strcmp(evnt.Modifier{:}, 'alt') && strcmp(evnt.Key,'s')
    RUNTEST = 0;
    fprintf('\nMyFunction: Operator quit by pressing (alt-s)\n');
end

return
```